# Thread runs sporadically when the screen is off

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a worker thread that starts running when an activity is started. It updates the UI elements while the screen is on by calling a callback. Now, when the app is in the background, the worker thread should keep working.

However, the thread gets wonky after turning the screen off. When the screen is on, the thread executes its work loop quite accurately, but that's not the case when the screen is off.

The debugging part I'm using for the thread's runnable looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(mRunning)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Tick");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            mRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this while the screen is on, the logcat output is rather consistent:

```
11-21 15:15:18.022    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:15:19.031    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:15:20.030    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:15:21.031    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:15:22.037    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
```

As you can see, it's pretty accurate and stays there right around in 1000 ms. However, when the screen is turned off, the output gets really random:

```
11-21 15:16:22.002    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:16:28.781    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:16:29.646    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:16:33.619    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
11-21 15:16:38.497    1424-2260/com.manabreak.threadedtest I/Worker: Tick
```

This is a lot more sporadic. First it sleep for almost seven seconds, then cycles in 900ms, then again four seconds... How do I keep the thread running more "smoothly"? The worker should work rather accurately and in a timely fashion.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider doing this into a Service instead of a thread. It fits better the Android platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`:

```
private WakeLock mWakeLock;

// Activity's onCreate()
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "worker");
    ...

    // The worker thread
    Thread t = new Thread(mRunnable);
    t.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(mWakeLock.isHeld()) mWakeLock.release();
}
```

If you do this, remember to add the permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```